# How to upload and read csv file import into database in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, import, csv, file-upload

How to upload the csv file and read import into the database magento 2?

```
<?php 

/**
* XXXX_ProductImport extension
* @category 
* @package XXXX_ProductImport
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2018
* @license Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
*/
namespace \ProductImport\Controller\Adminhtml\Imports;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 


use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action  
{
    protected $fileSystem;

    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $allowedExtensions = ['csv']; // to allow file upload types 

    protected $fileId = 'file'; // name of the input file box  

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
    ) {

        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $destinationPath = $this->getDestinationPath();

       $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
     $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        try {
            $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $this->fileId])
                ->setAllowCreateFolders(true)
                ->setAllowedExtensions($this->allowedExtensions)
                ->addValidateCallback('validate', $this, 'validateFile');


            if (!$uploader->save($destinationPath)) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                );
                return $resultRedirect;
            }

            // @todo
            // process the uploaded file
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __($e->getMessage())
            );
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }

    public function validateFile($filePath)
    {

        echo "hi";

        // @todo
        // your custom validation code here
    }

    public function getDestinationPath()
    {
        return $this->fileSystem
            ->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::TMP)
            ->getAbsolutePath('/');
    }
}
```